# PhpUnit unable to locate test files

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php, silex, autoloader

I am currently developing a rather large web application that uses *Silex* as a backend. I have added *PHPUnit* to the project created a simple test case:

```
class IndexControllerText extends BaseControllerTest
{
    public function testIndexPage()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

My `BaseControllerTest` is used to create the Application as [described in the docs](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/testing.html):

```
<?php
namespace VendorName\AppName\Tests;

use Silex\WebTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel;

abstract class BaseControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    public function createApplication()
    {
        $app = require __DIR__ . '/../../../../app/bootstrap.php';
        $app['debug'] = true;
        $app['exception_handler']->disable();

        return $app;
    }
}
```

My `app/bootstrap.php` loads the *composer* autoloader:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Silex\Application();

require_once __DIR__ . '/config.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/routing.php';

return $app;
```

And finally there is my `phpunit.xml` in my project root. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/ferdynator/73a8dc119b757687b75c).

Unfortunately when I run `phpunit -c phpunit.xml` the result says:

> No tests executed!

When I run the `IndexControllerTest` directly:

```
phpunit -c phpunit.xml src/VendorName/AppName/Tests/IndexControllerText.php
```

It runs the test and returns success as expected. I am pretty sure it's a configuration error within my `phpunit.xml` but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
     backupStaticAttributes="false"
     colors="true"
     convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
     convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
     convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
     processIsolation="false"
     stopOnFailure="false"
     syntaxCheck="false"
>
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="YourApp Test Suite">
        <directory>./tests/</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: You are not showing the file you suspect the error is in: `phpunit.xml`.

Comment: Its in the link i provided. It was too long for this post.

Comment: I counted that file to be less lines than your other code, and I added what I found on the page you linked. Please confirm this is the file you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I sense a typo:

```
IndexControllerText
```

This probably should be TEST with an S, not TEXT with an X.

Comment: Sometimes live can be so easy! Thank you!